# Simple recoil calcuation: Difference in answer from Momentum vs Energy approach

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum

I think I am completely misunderstanding a concept here.  Depending on my approach, I get two different answers, which I shouldnt (as I understand)/

```
The Setup:
```

A gun of mass $m_g$ and velocity $v_g$.  A bullet of mass $m_b$ and velocity $v_b$.  The combined mass and velocity is $m_c$ and $v_c$, respectively.
The bullet is fired from the gun and I seek to calculate the recoil velocity of the firearm.

```
Momentum approach:
```

Following the conservation of momentum:

$$ m_cv_c = m_bv_b + m_gv_g $$

The combined system has a velocity of $0$ at time $0$. The leads to the simplification that

$$  - m_gv_g = m_bv_b $$

which leads to the answer,

$$  v_g = -\frac{m_bv_b}{m_g} $$

```
Energy approach:
```

Following the conservation of energy:

$$ KE_c = KE_b + KE_g $$

this reduces to the following (remembering the $t_0$ condition),

$$  KE_g = -KE_b $$
$$ 1/2m_gv_g^2 = -1/2m_bv_b^2$$
$$ m_gv_g^2 = -m_bv_b^2$$
$$ v_g^2 = -\frac{m_bv_b^2}{m_g}$$
$$ v_g = \sqrt{-\frac{m_bv_b^2}{m_g}}$$

I think I made a mistake with the velocity's sign in the Energy approach.  But even if it is corrected, the two answers differ greatly and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Hint: Before firing, the gun & bullet have no KE, but the bullet contains chemical energy.

Comment: Keep in mind that $p_g+p_b\neq m_cv_c$

Comment: Thank you PM2Ring.  My energy approach was completely wrong.   Aaron, why would that not be the case?  Conservation of momentum leads to that expression, does it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no law that ensures $KE_g = −KE_b$ so you can't rely on that. You started with some energy, but then you added chemical energy of firing the gun.  And what does it mean for a kinetic energy to be negative in any case?

Because momentum is a vector (here, signed) quantity, you know that the two vectors have to be equal and opposite to sum to the zero you had before.

But the two energies just have to equal the total from firing the bullet; there's no other relation between them.  In fact, because E = $p^2/2m$, the bullet gets a lot more energy than the gun.

Comment: As PM2Ring commented, I failed to include chemical energy.  That was my biggest misinterpretation of the problem.  I failed in general with energy balance.  Thank you for the response